# I am using Photo Sphere Viewer and now I want to replace the panorama image to new one without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Can anyone tell me how can I can the panorama image to a new one on button click without the page reload?

Photo sphere viewer that I am using is https://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org

```
var PSVUtils = PhotoSphereViewer.Utils,
      fov = 70,
      PSV = new PhotoSphereViewer({
        panorama: 'images/vr-min.jpg', //want to change this image
        container: 'photo360',
        navbar: 'autorotate zoom download fullscreen',
        caption: 'vr',
        mousewheel: false,
        size: 800,
        time_anim: false,
        gyroscope: true,
        // webgl: PSVUtils.isWebGLSupported(),
        move_speed: 3,
        default_fov: fov + .01,
        min_fov: fov,
        max_fov: fov + .01,
        markers: [
          {
            // html marker with custom style
            id: 'text',
            longitude: -1.4,
            latitude: 0.12,
            html: '<a href="#" style="color:#fff;" onclick="myFunction()"><img id="myimg" src="https://png.icons8.com/color/260/circled-play.png" width="30" height="30" /></a>',
            anchor: 'bottom right',
            style: {
              maxWidth: '20px',
              color: 'white',
              fontSize: '20px',
              fontFamily: 'Helvetica, sans-serif',
              textAlign: 'center'
            },
            tooltip: {
              content: 'Watch this video for more details',
              position: 'right',
    height: '500px'
            }
          }
        ]
      });
```

I don't know what I can do to replace this image. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

```
PSV.setPanorama('new-pano.jpg', null, true);
```

will do the work for you.

suppose you have a marker with id "goto-pano", then,

```
PSV.on('select-marker', (marker) => {
  if (marker.id === 'goto-pano') {
    PSV.setPanorama('new-pano.jpg', null, true);
  }
});
```

or you can do it in any other button click event you have.